# PHP extract EXTR_OVERWRITE, does it work ONLY if collision exists?

Tags: php

PHP extract EXTR_OVERWRITE, does it work ONLY if collision exists?

```
extract(array_map($myclass->trim_value, $_POST), EXTR_OVERWRITE, "var_");
```

but i noticed that if i post `$_POST['id']` i get $id, not $var_id

does it mean that php automatically find collision and apply the rule only in that scenario? I also noticed that my trim_value, doesn't seem to work... what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$myclass->trim_value` Should that be a callback function ? What is saved in the property?

Comment: So were are we now? Question answered/solved?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it automatically detects if there is a collision, you can also read this in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

And a quote from there:

> **EXTR_OVERWRITE:**
>   **If there is a collision**, overwrite the existing variable.

If you want it for all variables use:

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "var_");
```